# Systems and methods claims

Tags: claims

The invention of interest is a system comprised of methods and a collection of tangible measurement device & electronic data collection systems.  [I was advised to avoid mixing:](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/19789/19913) the structure specification of the invention and a step in a process **in the same claim**.

Is there a specific guidance from the USPTO or in 35 USC? or is the guidance that one learns through experience/best practice?  I pose this question because if it is the former, then I would like to read the guidance so that my claims will conform to USPTO or other authoritative expectations.

Comment: United States code hardly ever provides guidance just law.

Answer (score 2):

May read https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2106.html for guidance.

Seems interpretation of

i.first sentence of 2106 - I "the claimed invention must be to one of the four statutory categories" and

ii. of 2106.03 - II last paragraph first line "If a claim is clearly not within one of the four categories (Step 1: NO), then a rejection under 35 U.S.C. 101 must be made indicating that the claim is directed to non-statutory subject matter." leads to practice of not mixing the cited two in your question '**in the same claim**'

However, **system and method** can be claimed in **two separate independent claims** in the same application.